# Adding to a \foreach variable in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I say sum multiple columns of a table using y expr while also using \foreach

I was hoping something like this would work but apparently it requires some sort of expression evaluation I can't get to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach \y in {1,3,5,7}
        \addplot table[x=Foo, y expr={\thisrowno{\y} + \thisrowno{\y+1}}] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The data:

```
Foo John John_a Paul Paul_a George George_a Ringo Ringo_a
1 0.0 37.0 0.00 9.00 0.0 4.0 0.0 12.80
2 16.0 5.0 4.0 1.0 0.6 2.80 0.0 12.80
4 8.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 0.3 2.8 0.0 12.80
8 4.0 5.0 1.0 1.0 0.4 2.8 0.0 12.80
16 2.0 5.0 1.2 1.0 0.4 2.8 0.0 12.80
32 1.0 5.0 1.3 1.0 0.5 2.8 0.0 12.80
```

Comment: Could you post a (short!) sample of your `data.csv` file, so your code can be compiled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to Jake's solution, you can use `\foreach`'s `evaluate` key, as shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Foo John John_a Paul Paul_a George George_a Ringo Ringo_a
1 0.0 37.0 0.00 9.00 0.0 4.0 0.0 12.80
2 16.0 5.0 4.0 1.0 0.6 2.80 0.0 12.80
4 8.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 0.3 2.8 0.0 12.80
8 4.0 5.0 1.0 1.0 0.4 2.8 0.0 12.80
16 2.0 5.0 1.2 1.0 0.4 2.8 0.0 12.80
32 1.0 5.0 1.3 1.0 0.5 2.8 0.0 12.80
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach[evaluate=\y as \ynext using int(\y+1)] \y in {1,3,5,7}
        \addplot table[x=Foo, y expr={\thisrowno{\y}+\thisrowno{\ynext}}] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Accepted for greater verbosity compared to Jake's.

Thanks for introducing me to these features.

Comment: No problem. Make good use of it :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I spoke to soon. I get a "Missing control sequence error" for the addplot line. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird; I don't get any error, here. Is your TeX distro up to date?

Comment: Aahhh, yes the latex installation provided by my work is horribly out of date. Now all is dandy. Thanks.

Comment: What if we need to evaluate multiple expressions in function of `\y` (e.g. `int(\y+1)` and `1/\y`)? How could we implement it then?

Answer (score 10):

Within an `axis` environment, you'll need to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead of the normal `\foreach`.

Note that you'll need to evaluate the sum (`\y+1` in your example) explicitly, e.g. using `\the\numexpr`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Foo John John_a Paul Paul_a George George_a Ringo Ringo_a
1 0.0 37.0 0.00 9.00 0.0 4.0 0.0 12.80
2 16.0 5.0 4.0 1.0 0.6 2.80 0.0 12.80
4 8.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 0.3 2.8 0.0 12.80
8 4.0 5.0 1.0 1.0 0.4 2.8 0.0 12.80
16 2.0 5.0 1.2 1.0 0.4 2.8 0.0 12.80
32 1.0 5.0 1.3 1.0 0.5 2.8 0.0 12.80     
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,3,5,7}{
        \addplot table[x=Foo, y expr={\thisrowno{#1} + \thisrowno{\the\numexpr #1+1}}] {data.csv};
        }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```