# Use variables in addplot in axis environment

Tags: pgfplots, expansion, axis

I wanted to make a macro `\simplePlotWithFuncs` creating plots both from `.csv` files and from given functions. I need it to be quite versatile, so I can set a lot of things. Because of limited number of parameters in the LaTeX macros I'm forced to use some of them for multiple arguments and parse those afterwards.

The problem is, this approach worked OK until I needed to give parameters to the `addplot` macro in `axis` environment. There I'm getting different errors and I don't know, how to solve this.

I have seen similar questions:

[\foreach not behaving in axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment)

[Using foreach loop variable as node label in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50477/using-foreach-loop-variable-as-node-label-in-pgfplots)

[Adding to a \foreach variable in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153185/adding-to-a-foreach-variable-in-pgfplots)

[Problems using \addlegendentry in a loop with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136427/problems-using-addlegendentry-in-a-loop-with-pgfplots)

But, unfortunately, I'm still not able to solve the problem.

---

#### My attempts

1. I've tried to use `\evaluate` parameter in pgfplots `\foreach` cycle:

   ```
   \foreach [evaluate=\datacol(1) as \datacolI] \datafile in {#1} {
   \addplot+[only marks, mark=square*] table [x=\datacolI, y=time, col sep=comma] {\datafile};
   \addtocounter{counter}{-1}
   }
   ```
2. I've also tried to use the construction `\edef\variable{\noexpand}`, but it doesn't work, too:

   ```
   \foreach \datafile in {#1} {
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+[only marks, mark=square*] table [x=\datacolI, y=time, col sep=comma] {\datafile}};
    \temp
    \addtocounter{counter}{-1}
   }
   ```

---

#### Error

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 70.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> main.tex

? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> main.tex

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

---

#### Code with my attempt

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfig}     % makra pro "podobrazky" a "podtabulky"
\usepackage{tikz}       % makra pro kresleni
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcounter{counter}

\newcommand{\simplePlotWithFuncs}[9]{
\newarray\labels
\readarray{labels}{#2}
\newarray\datacol
\readarray{datacol}{#3}
\edef\tmp{\datacol(1)}
\begin{figure}[hbtp!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:25, scale=0.75, transform shape]
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=\labels(1),
ylabel=\labels(2),
legend pos=#4,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
width=\textwidth*0.8,
height=\textwidth*0.5,
cycle list name = color list,
each nth point = 1,
filter discard warning=false
]
\setcounter{counter}{0}
\foreach [evaluate=\datacol(1) as \datacolI] \datafile in {#1} {
    \addplot+[only marks, mark=square*] table [x=\datacolI, y=time, col sep=comma] {\datafile};
\addtocounter{counter}{-1}
}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=\value{counter}-1}
\foreach \func in {#9} {
    \addplot+[mark=none, dashed]{\func};
}
\legend{#5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{#6}
\label{#7}
\smallskip
{\small #8}
\end{figure}
\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\simplePlotWithFuncs
    {ratioThProcs-size10.csv}
    {Number of processes & Time [s]}
    {nprocs&time}
    {north east}
    {size 10x10x10}
    {Stiffness matrix assembling speed dependence on decomposition style}   
    {fig:threadsProcsDecompDifference}
    {Fixed size of problem. Changing style of the decomposition - ratio of MPI processes and threads. Number of threads per process is computed by the formula $\frac{24}{nprocs}$. Points are measured values, dashed line is a hyperbola got by inverse regression.}
    {0.066181 + 0.548915/x}
\end{document}
```

#### CSV file

```
nprocs,nthreads,size,time
1,24,10,0.656395
2,12,10,0.256914
3,8,10,0.271941
4,6,10,0.174338
6,4,10,0.130503
8,3,10,0.123015
12,2,10,0.173938
24,1,10,0.114695
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work using the `\check` command from `arrarjobx` package:

- retrieve `datacol(1)` with the `\checkdatacol` command:

```
\newarray\datacol
\readarray{datacol}{#3}
\checkdatacol(1)
\edef\datacolI{\cachedata}
```

- then use `\datacolI` in your loop:

```
\foreach \datafile in {#1} {
    \addplot+[only marks, mark=square*] table [x=\datacolI, y=time, col sep=comma] {\datafile};
    \addtocounter{counter}{-1}
}
```